# priority_queue c++ with custom comparator and O(n) time

Tags: c++, constructor, find, c++17, priority-queue

I was searching but I didnt find an easy way to create a priority_queue using a cumstom comparator but that also takes linear time to create the elements in the priority_queue.

it is possible to create a priority_queue in linear time using:

```
vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4};
priority_queue<int> pq(arr.begin(),arr.end());
```

and it is possible to create a priority_queue using a custom comparator

```
auto cmp = [](int p1, int p2){return p1<p2};
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

I want know if it possible to do something like this:

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp,points.begin(),points.end());
```

Because if I create the priority_queue using the custom comparator and after I insert the values using push, the time complexity would be O (nlg (n))

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can see a list of available constructors here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue, none is worse than linear

Comment: What do you mean _"if it is possible"_? Did you face any problems whan trying?

Comment: It is possible to create a priority_queue with a custom comparator, and it is also possible to insert the elements in a priority_queue in linear time, but I searched a lot and I didnt find some way to usea a custom compator and also create the priority queue in linear time

Comment: what is wrong with the code you posted that does call the constructor with elements and custom comparator? Does it not compile?

Comment: I think you are looking for (13) in the link above. You just put the parameters in wrong order. What reference are you using? It is not possible to remember all such details and guessing wont work either.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding your question. We might be able to clear this up if we can see the comparator. It's pretty easy to write a comparator that meets the syntax requirements but fails the logical requirements enough to be very, very slow.

Comment: Thanks @463035818_is_not_a_number, that solve my problem, I am sorry if it was difficult to understand the question it is the first time I ask something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `points` is a container containing `std::vector<int>`s, this is how you could define your priority queue:

```
std::priority_queue<std::vector<int>,
                    std::vector<std::vector<int>>,
                    decltype(cmp)> pq(points.begin(), points.end(), cmp);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zEh89hWe4)

Comment: You should be able to just call `std::priority_queue pq(points.begin(), points.end(), cmp)` without specifying the templates.

Comment: `@Ranoiaetep Yes, absolutely. That works too.